# Modifying Netsuite Object on loading

Tags: encryption, netsuite

I am very new to Netsuite. I am trying to do encryption in Netsuite. It works when I add UserEvent Scripts beforeSubmit. But I wanted to decrypt the encrypted text in beforeLoad function. I am able to read the encrypted text and decrypt it successfully as well. But setting it back in the object fails and I see decrypted text in Netsuite UI. Any directions or help is appreciated.

thanks

// this function works

function beforeSubmit(type) {

```
    var email = nlapiGetFieldValue('email');
    var newEmail = 'LifeSpan.' + email;
    nlapiSetFieldValue('email', newEmail );
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Modified before Submit ' + email + ' to ' + newEmail);
```

}

// this printed "Modified before Submit customercare@abc.com to LifeSpan.customercare@abc.com"

// this function doesn't work; even though the correct value is printed correctly in the log

function beforeLoad(type, form, request) {

```
    var email = nlapiGetFieldValue('email');
    if(email.indexOf('SaaSSpan.') != -1) {
      var newEmail = email.substring(9);
      nlapiSetFieldValue('email', newEmail );
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Modified before load ' + email + ' to ' + newEmail);
    }
```

}

// this printed "Modified before load LifeSpan.customercare@abc.com to customercare@abc.com"...but I am still seeing LifeSpan.customercare@abc.com in the user interface

Comment: Please add some code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to try this code in a client script(PageInit and SaveRecord Events).

Works fine for me.

My Code :

```
function PageInit(type) {
try {
    if (type == 'edit') {
        var email = nlapiGetFieldValue('email');
        if (email != null && email.indexOf('LifeSpan.') != -1) {
            var newEmail = email.substring(9);
            nlapiSetFieldValue('email', newEmail);
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Modified before load ' + email + ' to ' + newEmail);
        }
    }
}
catch (err) {
    nlapiLogExecution('ERROR', 'PageInit', err);
}}

function SaveRecord() {
try {
    var email = nlapiGetFieldValue('email');
    var newEmail = 'LifeSpan.' + email;
    nlapiSetFieldValue('email', newEmail);
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Modified before Submit ' + email + ' to ' + newEmail);
}
catch (err) {
    nlapiLogExecution('ERROR', 'SaveRecord', err);
}
return true;}
```

nlapiSetFieldValue can be used in user event beforeLoad scripts to initialize field on new records or non-stored fields.

Comment: thanks, this worked. Is there to push this client side script to net-suite environment using API? I know we can do a file upload using API. Is there a way to assign client side scripts to specific objects (like say...i wanted to add these scripts for customer, lead (view, edit and create).

Comment: Is there a way to assign pageInit for create, lists, quick view etc. I have seen this happen only for copy, create and edit. How can I do the same for rest of the user interface screens?

Comment: You can assign your script to specific record in the script deployment page.

Comment: Can I do all of this in a automated way say calling an API or Webservice. We wanted to minimize manual intervention in the custom code deployment process if we can. Can we achieve that?

Comment: No,I dont think so. As far as I know there are only two ways to set a script onto a particular record.
1. Record level done through script Deployment page
2. Form level script by attaching the script to a particular record form(for only client scripts)